# Upload files on server. Invoking onclick method of <input> object

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have some problems.

I need to create page, that allow user to upload self files on server. I planning to use remote scripting for dynamical page update.

First requirement is not use javascript plugins.
Second - on the page will be placed button that may call dialog where user will can choose reuired files.

First i created hidden form:

```
<form style='display:none;'>
   <input id='fileUploader' type='file' name='fileName'>
</form>
```

Then i created button:

```
<button onclick='uploadFile();'>Add file</button>
```

Some code, that i wrote:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function uploadFile(){
    //get object handle
    var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
    // then i must create event object, that help me to invoke 
    // onclick method of my object
    if(document.createEvent){
        //this piece is for Firefox/Opera/etc....
        var o = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        o.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true);
        input.dispatchEvent(o);
    } else if (document.createEventObject) {
        var o = document.createEventObject();
        o.type = 'click';
        input.fireEvent('onclick',o);
    } else {
        console.log('your brouser is stupid')
    } 
  }
</script>
```

This code working on all browsers except IE (i tested on 8). But if i was test this method on another object, for example BUTTON or DIV  - all work, even on IE 8.

Can enyone say me what i does wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot fire a click event on an input of type `file` due to some security restrictions in IE. Once I tried the same with jQuery and failed with IE

Comment: it's bad wery bad... We write project for one specific device so we wery limited on resources, thats why we can't use js plugins, which may easy deside our problem. Ok... Thanks for all... I will think.

Comment: Is there any specific need to have the file selector triggered from outside? If what you want to achieve is to get rid of the default input button style, then you can manipulate with its styles a little bit.

Comment: No. Any specific needs. User must see only upload button witout any text fields near button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
o.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true);
```

To:

```
o.initMouseEvent( "click", true, true, window,
0, 0, 0, 80, 20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
```

IE will fire the document.createEvent. Passing all the arguments through initMouseEvent should allow it to work in all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/bz2LW/7/

Comment: IE said: “Object does not support this property or method” on dociment.createEven

Comment: createEvent method is supported by IE > 9 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx